# Creating draggable circle in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, maps, mapbox

Can you tell me how to create a **circle in leaflet which can be dragged across the map**?

I do **not** want to use **Circlemarkers** as i want to specify radius in meters and also the size  of circle should increase as we zoom in the map according to the distance it covers.

I want the radius in meters to show how many markers lie within that circle or that region. i want the dragging functionality so that user can **reposition the circle** across the map.

So basically i need to create a circle on the map which can be dragged across the map

i am using leaflet with mapbox for creating this application.

Answer (score 7):

leaflet does support onmouseup event. i just used your code and modified a bit to remove eventListener on mouseup. now it's working fine even if you pan your map.

```
   circle.on({
      mousedown: function () {
        map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
          circle.setLatLng(e.latlng);
        });
      }
   }); 
   map.on('mouseup',function(e){
     map.removeEventListener('mousemove');
   })
```

Here's a JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/akshay_agrawal/76wwqrvh/

Answer (score 3):

To make a circle draggable, you can add an event listener with a method for mousedown and one for click (from what I've seen, Leaflet doesn't support mouseup for Path layers). Inside the mousedown event, add a function to get the position of the circle from the current mouse position. Inside the click event, remove the previous event listener to make the circle stay where you want.

```
circle.on({
  mousedown: function () {
    map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
      circle.setLatLng(e.latlng);
    });
  },
  click: function () {
    map.removeEventListener();
  }
});
```

Comment: Saddenly, this doesn't work anymore after you've panned the map. Looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have had to solve this problem recently. None of the above answers seem to give reliable click and drag or press and drag across browsers and devices.

My solution involved [Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) with a small modification to the code.

If you look at the [Leaflet.draw Edit Handlers example](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/examples/edithandlers.html) you will see that the Circle type is able to be dragged but also resized.

Resizing was not desired for me so I made a quick alteration to the [Edit.Circle.js](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/master/src/edit/handler/Edit.Circle.js) where I simply commented out line 14 which remove the resize square and leave the move function.

Either rebuild or using the source js scripts (make sure you import the modified Edit.Circle.js) as is in the Leaflet.draw example above it is simple then to add a draggable circle:

```
var circle = L.circle([51.53, -0.06], 600);

circle.editing.enable();

map.addLayer(circle);
```

Probably not the most streamline solution but functionality wise works best for me.

OK so if you plan to delete the circle layer another modification needs to be made, this time to Edit.SimipleShape.js in the removeHooks. I put checks in place to skip over _resizeMarkers and _markerGroup if the are null. Seems to work OK now.